# ¿Còmo se implementa una clase en C++ usando TADs?

Tags: c++, clase

tengo dudas de como implementar una clase, ya que mirando código autogenerado en Codeblocks, veo que implementa los getter y setter en el archivo .h, ¿esto no es incorrecto? ya que tenía entendido que acá solo iban los encabezados de los procedimientos.

El .h autogenerado del Codeblocks:

```
#ifndef SOCIO_H
#define SOCIO_H

class Persona
{
    public:
        Persona();
        virtual ~Persona();

        string Getci() { return ci; }
        void Setci(string val) { ci = val; }
        string Getnombre() { return nombre; }
        void Setnombre(string val) { nombre = val; }

    protected:

    private:
        string ci;
        string nombre;
        Fecha fechaIngreso;
};

#endif // SOCIO_H
```

Por otro lado, los *Data Types* se que se implementan como las clases, ¿a estos también les corresponde un archivo ".h"?

Comment: ¿A que llamas un *Data Types*? implementar las funciones en el .cpp es una recomendacion, no es una obligacion.

Comment: Data Type es un descriptor de un conjunto de valores que no tienen identidad, como Fecha, Enteros, etc. En C++ sè que se utilizan clases y se implementan igual, pero no se si se separa de esa forma, con .h y .cpp

Comment: Hay dos preguntas aquí, una sobre el código y otra sobre la relación entre TAD y clases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Implementa los getter y setter en el archivo .h, ¿esto no es incorrecto?

Ni correcto ni incorrecto. Depende del contexto. Generalmente se separa la declaración en archivo de cabecera (`.h` o `.hpp`) y definición en archivo de código (`.cpp`) para seguir los principios de [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)) ya que ésto permite ocultar los detalles de implementación al usuario de la clase.

Pero un getter y un setter habitualmente ocupan una línea de código o poco más y tienen un comportamiento bastante obvio, así que ocultar los detalles de implementación de esas funciones en concreto es como ocultar un secreto a voces.

Los archivos de cabecera (`.h` o `.hpp`) suelen ser la interfaz pública de una clase; si desarrollaeses una librería sobre la que entregas tan sólo el código ya compilado (`.lib` o `.dll`) necesitarías las cabeceras para indicar al usuario de tu librería cómo usar tu clase.

> Tenía entendido que acá solo iban los encabezados de los procedimientos.

En un archivo de cabecera puedes poner tanto las declaraciones (encabezados de procedimientos) como las definiciones (el cuerpo de los procedimientos), no hay ninguna restricción al respecto, tan sólo las restricciones impuestas por las necesidades de tu proyecto.

> Por otro lado, los Data Types se que se implementan como las clases.

Esto es falso, una clase se implementa, un tipo de datos puede ser una clase, estructura, unión, enumerado o alias... los cuatro primeros pueden tener implementación mientras que el alias no se implementa: es. Otros objetos son también tipos de datos pero de una complejidad diferente como plantillas y lambdas; las primeras (salvo excepciones) sólo disponen de implementación (carecen, salvo excepciones, de definición) y las lambdas son tan sólo definición sin declaración.

> ¿A éstos tambièn les corresponde un archivo ".h"?

El archivo de cabecera, en general, contiene las declaraciones; pero no hay nada que impida que contengan también las implementaciones (definiciones).

Answer (score 2):

> implementa los getter y setter en el archivo .h, ¿esto no es incorrecto?

Como te han dicho, no hay una norma escrita que obligue a implementar las funciones en la cabecera o en el fichero de implementación... cada opción tiene sus ventajas y sus inconvenientes:

**Implementación en cabecera**

- Ventaja: Las funciones pueden ser `inline`, lo que *puede* acelerar la ejecución del código
- Inconveniente: Cualquier cambio en la cabecera, aunque no afecte a la interfaz de la clase, obliga a compilar todos los ficheros que incluyan directa o indirectamente dicha cabecera -> Más tiempo de compilación.
- Inconveniente: Degenera el concepto de encapsulación
- Inconveniente: `inline` no funciona con funciones virtuales en entornos polimórficos) ni con funciones excesivamente complejas (el compilador es el que decide).

**Implementación en fichero independiente**

- Ventaja: Modificar los detalles de la implementación solo requiere compilar el fichero modificado
- Ventaja: La implementación queda oculta a ojos de los clientes
- Ventaja: Si la implementación requiere de terceras clases no será necesario incluir dichas clases en la cabecera (Menos dependencias en cabeceras = Menos tiempo de compilación)
- Inconveniente: No se puede beneficiar de `inline`

> ya que tenía entendido que acá solo iban los encabezados de los procedimientos.

Cuando descubras las plantillas verás que las mismas tienen que estar declaradas e implementadas en un fichero de cabecera para poder utilizarlas.

Esto que comentas no es para nada exacto... otra cosa sería decir que "*como norma general es recomendable dejar las cabeceras para las declaraciones*"

> Por otro lado, los Data Types se que se implementan como las clases, ¿a estos también les corresponde un archivo ".h"?

**Todos** los elementos de tu aplicación que vayan a estar disponibles por la aplicación en general necesitan una cabecera... Si el ámbito de una clase, tipo, función, enumerado, etc. queda relegado a una implementación concreta no hay ningún motivo que impida declarar este elemento en el fichero de implementación correspondiente:

**`POO.h`**

```
// Guardas omitidas ...

struct POO
{
  void func();
};
```

**`POO.cpp`**

```
#include "poo.h"

// Esta funcion solo va a ser utilizada por la implementacion de POO
// No existe en ninguna cabecera, luego no va a estar disponible en
// el resto del programa
static void FuncionInterna()
{ std::cout << "1\n"; }

void POO::func()
{ FuncionInterna(); }
```